# Linq Over EntityFramework edmx error Invalid expression where

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, iqueryable

Using VS 2013, and SQL Server 2012, I have a C# linq query in what will become a simple SQL CLR user defined function. To wit:

```
string userId = from uid in GEN_Application_Attribute
                where uid.Attribute_name == "S1WebServices_usrId"
                select uid.Attribute_value;

string passWord = from pw in GEN_Application_Attribute
                where pw.Attribute_name == "S1WebServices_pwd"
                select Attribute_value;
```

GEN_Application_Attribute is an EF object (v.5, I think) shown in an EDMX. I keep getting an error, "Invalid expression term 'where'". My research suggests this is a result of the EDMX not implementing IQueryable on the entity objects. (One wonders. why the heck not?) What I haven't been able to figure out is, how do I fix it? I've tried IQueryable<GEN_Application_Attribute>, some sort of CAST on the two sqlString datatypes, that I didn't understand, and some other odds and ends.

This just can't be that difficult! Sprint ends today, so I re-did this as SQL OLE, but I hate that approach.

Help?

**EDITED:**

The rest of the SQL CLR calls a web function -- this fragment, obviously, just gets the userId and password for the function, and is the only error in the code (I tried with literals for userId and passwords and got correct results).

Comment: Does `string userId=GEN_Application_Attribute.First(a=>a.Attribute_name=="S1WebServices_usrId").Attribute_value;` work? `from uid in GEN_Application_Attribute
                where uid.Attribute_name == "S1WebServices_usrId"
                select uid.Attribute_value` would return a `IQueryable<string>` btw.

Comment: You've probably already tried it, but I can't tell you how many times I've solved EDMX issues by removing a table from the model and readding it.

Comment: Antrim, yeah, that's my next step. I've never found EF to be that useful. But, I just work here.

Comment: Robert, the book says it should, but when I query the table directly, using LinqPad, it comes back as a plain string. Of course I've tried it both ways in the project and can't get past the invalid 'where'.

Comment: One other question I have, is why did I have to dig through the build output to see this error, while the VS Error List shows squat?